# path across a grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question : how many number of shortest path from the yellow bottom left corner to the yellow top right corner?

At first, I thought the answer will be $12!/(6!\cdot6!)$. But, I just realized that the combination of 6 consecutive to the north will not work here. Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly any shortest path can only go up or right.

So just work out the number of shortest paths to each point which may be on a correct route.  I have not checked the arithmetic, but something like

[image]

You could check this by considering those of the ${12 \choose 6}$ routes not through the blue circles (taking account of those going through more than one in the middle column).  This is ${12 \choose 6}-{4 \choose 0}{8 \choose 6} - {4 \choose 1}{8 \choose 5} -{8 \choose 6}{4 \choose 0} - \left({8 \choose 5}- {4 \choose 1}{4\choose 4}\right) {4 \choose 1}$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that we move along lines (not cells), starting at S and ending at E:

[image]

I take for granted that we know that all possible shortest paths for a full $n \times m$ grid is ${n+m \choose m} = {n+m \choose n}$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498585/number-of-distinct-paths-in-a-rectangular-grid)).

Let $N(A,B)$ the number of paths from point $A$ to point $B$.

We have then:

$$N(S,E) = [N(S,1)-N(S,2)]N(1,4)N(4,E)+[N(S,2)-N(S,3)][N(2,4)-N(2,5)]N(4,E)+[N(S,2)-N(S,3)]N(2,5)N(5,E)+N(S,3)[N(3,4)-N(3,5)]N(4,E)+N(S,3)[N(3,5)-N(3,6)]N(5,E)+N(S,3)N(3,6)N(6,E) = \left[{6 \choose 2}-{5 \choose 2}\right]{2 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}+\left[{5 \choose 2}-{4 \choose 2}\right]\left[{3 \choose 2}-{2 \choose 2}\right]{4 \choose 2}+\left[{5 \choose 2}-{4 \choose 2}\right]{2 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 2}\left[{4 \choose 2}-{3 \choose 2}\right]{4 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 2}\left[{3 \choose 2}-{2 \choose 2}\right]{5 \choose 2}+{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2} = 436$$

Where, for example, $N(S,1)-N(S,2)$ count all paths from $S$ to $1$ not passing by $2$, and similarly for other subtractions.

The result agrees with the answer by @Henry.